# What's good to create a page component in React?

Tags: reactjs

While i can understand you can build React components like button, list ...
some ppl suggests to create page component as well.

This confuses me, since to me page is on top of these UI components (button, list, ...), it uses these components.
So what's the advantage to make page itself as an component ?

Comment: page components allow you to implement navigation-like behavior without document refreshes in single-page applications

Comment: ok, so it's a SPA component, that make sense.

Comment: btw anyone recommend some good samples of SPA react component ? Thx !